# make a query string from a list

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I have some saved text in a session list that i want to save in a database. Currently,
result holds 4 different strings.

```
List<string> result = (List<string>)HttpContext.Current.Session["Application"];

foreach (string element in result)
{
    //produce a query string?        
}
```

I am using oracle database and a query string for the other inserts for example:

```
string sql = "insert into JOBQUESTIONS (JOBAPPLICATIONID, QUESTIONTEXT, TYPEID, HASCORRECTANSWER, CORRECTANSWER, ISREQUIRED) VALUES (" + JobID + ", \'" + QuestionText + "\', " + TypeID + ", " + HasCorrectAnswer + ", \'" + CorrectAnswer + "\', " + IsRequired + ")";
RunQuery(sql);
```

So, i need to create a set of values. However keep in mind these are all strings so i will need to have \'  \'  like: \'" + CorrectAnswer + "\' for all entries of strings or it wont add to the database.

Can i use string builder? If so how?

Comment: please use parameters :)

Comment: That's a sql injection attack begging to happen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you building a SQL String (That opens you up to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection))? I would suggest either using an ORM ([Entity Framework is the MSDN ORM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), or a sproc that will do this (and use [SqlParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx)). Or, at minimum you should be using a parameterized string instead of pushing values in directly

```
var parameterizedQuery = new SqlCommand(
    "INSERT INTO JOBQUESTIONS (JOBAPPLICATIONID, 
        QUESTIONTEXT, TYPEID, HASCORRECTANSWER, CORRECTANSWER, ISREQUIRED) 
    VALUES (@JobId, '@QuestionText', @TypeID , @HasCorrectAnswer , '@CorrectAnswer',
        @IsRequired)");

parameterizedQuery.Parameters.Add("@JobId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 123;
```

Comment: That would be a better approach, but it's not what OP asked for. Answer the question first and then offer a better solution.

Comment: @JamesJohnson The correct answer does not always mean a direct one. I know there is a meta post on this, but I cannot find it atm

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
var parms = string.Join(",", lst.Select(str => string.Format("'{0}'", str)));

var values = string.Format("VALUES({0})", parms);
```

As others have suggested, using a parameterized query would be better and safer, so if you choose to go that route I would consider switching to a `Dictionary` instead of a `List`.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

dict.Add("Foo", "Bar"); //parameter name, value
dict.Add("Bar", "Foo"); //...

dict.Select(d => cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(string.Format("@{0}", d.Key), d.Value));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use parametrized query. This means you only insert some temporaty names into sql query like

```
"INSERT INTO tablename VALUEs(@param1, @param2, ...)";
```

then you define parameters:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.Int).Value = your actual value";
```